# I am stuck on multiplicativePersistence algorithm question. I don't know why this code is not working

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Have the function MultiplicativePersistence(num) take the num parameter being passed which will always be a positive integer and return its multiplicative persistence which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.

For example: if num is 39 then your program should return 3 because 3 * 9 = 27 then 2 * 7 = 14 and finally 1 * 4 = 4 and you stop at 4.

My code works well. But test case is saying this is not correct one. Could you guys tell me why it is not working?

```
var userInput = prompt("Enter a num:");

var MultiplicativePersistence = function(num) {
  var arr = num.toString().split('');
  var multiplicative = 1;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr.length === 1){
      return Number(arr[0]);
    } 
    multiplicative *= Number(arr[i]);
  }

  if(multiplicative < 10){
    return multiplicative;
  }

   return MultiplicativePersistence(multiplicative);
};

console.log(MultiplicativePersistence(userInput));
```

when entering 786, test case says correct answer is 4. 
But I think the correct answer is 0. Am I wrong?

Comment: The correct answer can't be 0 if the goal is to find the "**number of times** you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit". If the answer was 0, that would mean that 786 is a single digit number, but it's not. You don't seem to need to find the final number. 7x8x6=3x3x6=5x4=9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you're getting is 0 because the last calculation your function is doing is '2 * 0' which equals 0. You are then returning this value.

It looks like you should return the number of multiplications you have to do (the number of times you run your function) instead of the result.

You could solve this by tracking the number of times the function runs in a global variable and returning that instead.

```
var userInput = prompt("Enter a num:");
var numberOfTimesFunctionRuns = 0;

var MultiplicativePersistence = function(num) {
  var arr = num.toString().split('');
  var multiplicative = 1;
  numberOfTimesFunctionRuns++;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr.length === 1){
      return numberOfTimesFunctionRuns;
    } 
    multiplicative *= Number(arr[i]);
  }

  if(multiplicative < 10){
    return numberOfTimesFunctionRuns;
  }

   return MultiplicativePersistence(multiplicative);
};

console.log(MultiplicativePersistence(userInput));
```